# ClassCastException while de-serializing(loading into hive table) decimals written in avro schema backed Parquet format

Tags: hive, avro, parquet

I am trying to serialize csv data in to Parquet format using Avro Schema(Avro Backed) & again reading that into hive tables.

This is successfully getting serialized using following sample code snippet(Sample code to serialize one single record):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter;
import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.metadata.CompressionCodecName;
import org.apache.parquet.schema.MesspidType;

public class AvroParquetConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Schema avroSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("schema.avsc"));
        GenericRecord myrecord = new GenericData.Record(avroSchema);
        String outputFilename = "/home/jai/sample1000-snappy.parquet";
        Path outputPath = new Path(outputFilename);
        MesspidType parquetSchema = new AvroSchemaConverter()
                .convert(avroSchema);
        AvroWriteSupport writeSupport = new AvroWriteSupport(parquetSchema,
                avroSchema);
        CompressionCodecName compressionCodecSnappy = CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY;
        int blockSize = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
        int ppidSize = 64 * 1024;

        ParquetWriter parquetWriterSnappy = new ParquetWriter(outputPath,
                writeSupport, compressionCodecSnappy, blockSize, ppidSize);
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(20);
        GenericRecord myrecordTemp = new GenericData.Record(avroSchema);
        myrecord.put("name", "Abhijeet1");
        myrecord.put("pid", 20);
        myrecord.put("favorite_number", 22);
        String bd1 = "13.5";
        BigDecimal bdecimal = new BigDecimal(bd1);
        bdecimal.setScale(15, 6);
        BigInteger bi = bdecimal.unscaledValue();
        byte[] barray = bi.toByteArray();
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(barray.length);
        byteBuffer.put(barray);
        byteBuffer.rewind();
        myrecord.put("price", byteBuffer);
        parquetWriterSnappy.write(myrecord);
        parquetWriterSnappy.close();
    }
}
```

Tried decimal to bytebuffer conversion is done using following statement as well:

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(bdecimal.unscaledValue().toByteArray());
```

Following is the avro schema file

```
{
    "namespace": "avropoc",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "User",
    "fields": [
             {"name": "name", "type": "string", "default" : "null"},
             {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": "int", "default": 0 },
             {"name": "pid",  "type":"int", "default" : 0 },
             {"name": "price", "type": {"type" : "bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":15,"scale":6}, "default" : 0 }
     ]
}
```

Also tried following modification in to schema:

```
{"name": "price", "type": "bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":15,"scale":6, "default" : 0 }
```

And I am creating Hive table as follows:

```
create external table avroparquet1
( name string, favorite_number int,
pid int, price DECIMAL(15,6))
STORED AS PARQUET;
```

But when I am running a query for decimal field price I am getting following error message:

> Failed with exception
>   java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable
>   cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.HiveDecimalWritable

This looks like parquet/avro/hive related issue where it is not able to deserialize Decimals which in case of avro needs to be written as ByteBuffer.

I have tried this on avro 1.8.0, parquet 1.8.1 & Hive 1.1.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The actual Schema generated by Hive for a DECIMAL(22,7) -- using some code derived from [that LinkedIn utility](https://github.com/azkaban/azkaban-plugins/blob/master/plugins/hdfsviewer/src/azkaban/viewer/hdfs/ParquetFileViewer.java) to inspect the actual Parquet files -- looks like...

- Parquet syntax: `optional fixed_len_byte_array(10) my_dec_22_7;`
- AVRO syntax:`{ "name":"my_dec_22_7","type":["null",{"type":"fixed", "name":"my_dec_22_7","size":10} ], "default":null }`

...where 10 appears to be the number of bytes required to dump a `BigInteger` with 22 digits into a `byte[]`. Look into [AvroSerdeUtils](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hive/hive-serde/1.2.1/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/avro/AvroSerdeUtils.java#189) source code and the way it dumps a `HiveDecimal`, for example.

That being said, I don't really know how to read/write a DECIMAL in a Parquet file. DOUBLE and BIGINT are much easier to handle since they are backed by IEEE standard types (and AVRO standard types, and Parquet standard types).